# Can I only draw the outline of a shape file without the borders within the shape file

Tags: r, plot, shapefile, rgdal

I am using `rgdal` to `plot` a shapefile:

```
 library(rgdal)
 shp <- readOGR(...)
 plot(shp, ...)
```

Because the shape file contains administrative areas, the plotted image is drawn with borders *inside* the shape. I'd rather not having them drawn. Is this somehow possible?